# Need to export a feature dataset into a new geodatabase

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, file-geodatabase, feature-dataset

I am having trouble trying to export a feature dataset into a .gdb that I have created. I am working on data in ArcMap 10.2 that is located in my d drive (D:). I have created a folder and a (for example)test.gdb in my p drive where I want my test.gdb located. However, when I right click the feature dataset in my table of contents (because that is the only thing I want to export) and click on "export," I am confused on what to do next.

For my output I choose the path of the feature dataset I want to export. My input, I choose the folder in which I want my dataset to go too (p:\test.gdb). There is another "input" section that I am not sure what to insert as the path.

Comment: Just from memory, that field should be what you want to call the exported feature class. You can just name it the same thing the original dataset is called, if you like.

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't accept it.

Comment: Why not copy and paste in catalog? It should be from data, to workspace then name. The geodatabase should exist before you try to put data in it. Is test.gdb just a folder or did you create a file geodatabase using ArcCatalog? Are you exporting in ArcMap or ArcCatalog???

Comment: Use Save As, pick File and Geodatabase...

Comment: From data, to workspace (new folder/test.gdb), then name like test? I created the file geodatabase using ArcCatalog. I am exporting using ArcMap. Should I try exporting using ArcCatalog?

Comment: Export from ArcMap will honor your definition queries (and selection if you choose) so there is benefits there. Normally though a Catalog copy/paste is preferable if you want a direct copy. I think though you're exporting a feature class not a feature dataset (slightly different). The input select tells ArcMap to export all the features or just the ones that you have selected (sometimes useful).

Comment: Follow @Michael Miles-Stimson suggestion. Copy/Paste the feature dataset.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to keep all features, topologies, schema, metadata, etc. intact; I recommend using the [Export Workspace Document (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000015s000000) tool. Then, navigate to your new GDB, right click, import, XML Workspace Document, select the XML workspace you created from the old GDB, and you should be good to go.